# Error converting CLLocationCoordinate2D to CLLocation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cllocationmanager, cloudkit

I am trying to convert a cllocationcoordinate2d into a cllocation. I get the error "Expected expression in container literal" on line 12 of the code below.  I also get the error "Cannot convert value of type cllocationcoordinate2d into expected value cllocation" on line 13 but that is because line 12 isn't working correctly.

```
@IBAction func makeEvent(sender: UIButton)
    {
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: loc1.coordinate.latitude, longitude: loc1.coordinate.longitude)
        let lat: CLLocationDegrees = center.latitude
        let long: CLLocationDegrees = center.longitude
        self.pointAnnotation1 = MKPointAnnotation()
        self.pointAnnotation1.title = "Event"
        self.pointAnnotation1.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
        self.pinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: self.pointAnnotation1, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        self.mapView?.centerCoordinate = self.pointAnnotation1.coordinate
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(self.pinAnnotationView.annotation!)
        CLLocation *center = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latt longitude:longg]
        eventRecord.setObject(center, forKey: "event")
        let publicData = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
        publicData.saveRecord(eventRecord) { record, error in
        }
        if error == nil
        {
            print("Location saved")
        }
        loadEvent(){ (error, records) in
            if error != nil {
                print("error fetching locations")
            } else {
                print("Found Event")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `CLLocation *center = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latt longitude:longg]` is Objective-C, not Swift.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are mixing up Objective-C and Swift.

Try this:

```
let center = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
```

Instead of:

```
CLLocation *center = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latt longitude:longg]
```